# Serverfarm cannot be found when executing the terraform scripts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, terraform, azure-app-service-plans

I am kind of new to Terraform and i am trying to set up Infrastructure using terraform for my Organization. I am in a case where i am having the *app_service_plan* al ready been deployed to azure and now i am trying to use the same to my *app_service* which i want to create using terraform scripts.

The following is my *app_service* snippet:

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "test-rg" {
  name = "test-rg"
}

data "azurerm_app_service_plan" "test-asp" {
  name = "test-asp"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "test-app" {
  name                = "test-app"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.test-rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.test-rg.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.test-asp.id
 }
```

But i am getting a **ServerFarm** not found error, this is what the error looks like:

```
 Error: Error creating App Service "test-app" (Resource Group "test-rg"): web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="NotFound" Message="Cannot find ServerFarm with name test-asp." Details=[{"Message":"Cannot find ServerFarm with name test-asp."},{"Code":"NotFound"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"NotFound","ExtendedCode":"51004","Message":"Cannot find ServerFarm with name test-asp.","MessageTemplate":"Cannot find {0} with name {1}.","Parameters":["ServerFarm","test-asp"]}}]
```

I also tried to import this *app_service_plan* into my terraform state and this is how my *app_service_plan* is been populated by me after importing it:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "test-asp"{
    is_xenon                     = false
    kind                         = "linux"
    location                     = "eastus2"
    maximum_elastic_worker_count = 1
    name                         = "test-asp"
    per_site_scaling             = false
    reserved                     = true
    resource_group_name          = "test-rg"

    sku {
        capacity = 1
        size     = "B1"
        tier     = "Basic"
    }
}
```

And here is my import command :

```
terraform import azurerm_app_service_plan.test-asp /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/test-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/test-asp
```

Can anyone suggest me the way by which i can use this already existing *app_service_plan* for my *app_service*. Thank You.

Comment: Just to check the app service plan is in the same resource group and region (location) as the App service?

Comment: test-app is too generic i assume it already exists somewhere but you dont have access

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Not yet, i for now hardcoded the serverfarm id

Answer (score 2):

In this case, make sure that you have created an app service in the **same region** as your service plan. Also, you need to specify the service plan matched your app service. For example, you can create a windows application app on a windows based service plan and a Linux application app on a Linux based service plan.

Perhaps, there are some typos in your example. When you use [Data Source: azurerm_app_service_plan](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/app_service_plan), you should input the `name` and `resource_group_name` Argument Reference and reference the `app_service_plan_id` with the data source.

So change your code to

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "test-rg" {
  name = "test-rg"
}

data "azurerm_app_service_plan" "test-asp" {
  name                = "test-asp"
  resource_group_name = "test-rg"    # or data.azurerm_resource_group.test-rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "test-app" {
  name                = "test-app"
  location            = data.azurerm_app_service_plan.test-asp.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.test-rg.name
  app_service_plan_id = data.azurerm_app_service_plan.test-asp.id
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

### I had the same issue when I was trying to deploy web app for containers in azure. putting the **location** for my ***App service plan*** AND ***Web-app for containers service*** solved my issue. Here below my example

## Create an App Service Plan with Linux

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {
  name                = "MyServicePlan-ContainerApp"
  location            = "westeurope"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  # Define Linux as Host OS
  kind     = "Linux"
  reserved = true # Mandatory for Linux plans
  # Choose size
  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}
```

LOCAL environment vars are required if you want to push an image to your Azure Container Registry (ACR)

```
locals {
 env_variables = {
   DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL            = "{URL TO DOCKER REGISTRY}"
   DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME       = "{ADMIN USERNAME of ACR}"
   DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD       = "{ADMIN PASS for ACR}"
 }
}
```

## Create an Azure Web App for Containers in that App Service Plan

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "my-app-service-container" {
 name                    = "my-app-service-container"
 location                = "westeurope"
 resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
 app_service_plan_id     = azurerm_app_service_plan.appserviceplan.id
 https_only              = false
 client_affinity_enabled = true
 site_config {
   scm_type  = "VSTSRM"
   always_on = "true"


   health_check_path = "/health" # health check required in order that internal app service plan load balancer do not load-balance on instance down
 }

 app_settings = local.env_variables 
}
```